# Extract Exif data from Tif

Tags: image, matlab, tiff, exif

i have this code here and i would like to make it simpler by not using tif and cr2. basicly i would like to get exposure time fnumber iso and the date from the tif as variables t f S date, so that i don't have to use the cr2 file. here is my code so far:

```
clear all % clear workspace
RGB = imread('IMG_0069.tif');

info = imfinfo('IMG_0069.CR2'); % get Metadata
C = 1; % Constant to adjust image

x = info.DigitalCamera; % get EXIF
t = getfield(x, 'ExposureTime');% save ExposureTime
f = getfield(x, 'FNumber'); % save FNumber
S = getfield(x, 'ISOSpeedRatings');% save ISOSpeedRatings   
date = getfield(x,'DateTimeOriginal'); % save DateTimeOriginal

I = rgb2gray(RGB);
```

Comment: Is that information encoded in the TIFF? have you tried calling `iminfo` to the tiff?

Comment: i get this msg :Reference to non-existent field 'DigitalCamera'. i think it should be encoded

Comment: Then it is likely that the information is not encoded in the TIFF file!

Comment: well is there a way to make it simpler? maybe that it automaticly goes for the cr2 file with the same name as the tif?

Comment: works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily concatenate strings to from names.

```
fname='IMG_XXX'; 
imread([fname, '.tif']);
iminfo([fname,'.CR2'])
```

`iminfo` should give you any info encoded in the metadata, but from the comments I can see that your files have not the information you want.

Comment: fname='IMG_0041'; % select target image

    RGB = imread([fname, '.tif']);% Read Image as tif
    info = imfinfo([fname,'.CR2']); % get Metadata from CR2